# Different ways to say "Grandpa" in (Mexican) Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, coloquialismos, méxico, parentesco

I know grandfather is *Abuelo*, but are there more [affectionate terms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12111/18348)? I mean like there's Grandpa, Gramps, Grandpappy, Granddad, etc. in English, which are more informal than grandfather.

Something a kid might refer to a favourite Grandpa from Mexico as, I guess.

Comment: In Spain, it's usual to use **"Yayo"**, it's the term that kids use to call Grandparents when they don't know how to speak correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mexico, there are two common choices for this:

**Abuelito**

**Abue**

They're both extremely common.

Comment: *Abue* also can be used indirectly, for instance: "*Fue lo que le dije a mi Abue*" or "*Mi Abue es el mejor del mundo*"

Comment: @Phi - You're right!

Answer (score 6):

> I know grandfather is Abuelo, but are there more affectionate terms?

In general, **using the diminutive form** of words in Latin American Spanish context is considered a form of affectionate variation. The specific reason, as per my understanding, is that "smaller" things (like little dogs, etc.) tend to inspire protective instincts, as well as a sense of "cuteness".

The same applies to *Abuelo*; by saying **"Abuelito"** you are conveying a more affectionate tone to it.

Another variation I've heard is using the word **"Papito"** along with your grandpa's name (like, for example, *Papito Juan*). This conveys the meaning that, being your father's father, you also consider your grandpa your "papi" (from *padre*, which is masculine form of *parent*).

This one I've noticed is *common along those cases where your father and grandfather have the same name*, as to avoid confusion when calling or talking to them. That way, you can affectionate refer to both as, i.e.: *"Papito Juan"* and *"Papi Juan"*, for your grandfather and father, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve heard and used Tata and Uelo(welo)  short for abuelo

Comment: Can you expand this to provide more information like where you heard this and in what circumstances? Welcome to the site and we hope to see your contributions in future.